# Elegant way of getting gray scale pixels from a scanned image

Tags: image-processing, handwriting

I will have scanned images with gray toned handwriting on white background.

What is the elegant way of selecting, and getting pixels of gray level(non-white) contigous areas?

Which image processing library should i use?

So far i research for a class and method in Leptonica, but found method names like: seedfill, i do not want to fill the area i want to get pixel coordinates that make the contigous area.

So can you also share class name with library name?

Thanks for reading and possible response.

Comment: I am using C++, but i think i can use Java through JNI, but i do not know if it is expensive about time or memory

Comment: If you care about performance it will be better to stick with C++. Using JNI is definitely an overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am going to try opencv but i must use JNI for a different job, is it really a performance problem?

Comment: It is not necessarily a performance *problem* but it has a more or less noticable cost. It depends on what you do whit it (number of method calls, number and type of parameters). It's just that when you can use a C++ library, I would go with that.

Comment: ok, thanks, i do not have another choice for that different job, thus i am going to use JNI for it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). Maybe the [findContours](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours) function is what you want.

Comment: One more and last question, what is the best way to get the pixels in the contour, because if i understand right findContours returns frame of the contiguous area.

Comment: Yes, it will return the frames of contiguous areas. [drawContours](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#drawcontours) or [fillPoly](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly) could help.